# how to change version of jars like nekohtml and log4j-slf4j

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, pom.xml

when the maven build is triggered, i see nekohtml and log4j-slf4j libraries being downloaded. but when i check my pom i don't see any where these jars mentioned. i want to change version of these jars. are these being downloaded because of some other jars..? some time when i clear my local repo, progress bar in eclipse shows that dependencies are being downloaded from maven repo and these jars are downloaded even before i trigger maven build. can you please help by telling where can i change version of these jars

Comment: start with `mvn dependency:tree`

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly add the version you want because some other dependencies may be fetching their own versions of the jars. You will need to find out which dependencies are causing them to be downloaded using `mvn dependency:tree` and then exclude them to avoid conflicts at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using those dependencies in your code?

- Yes

Then add those dependencies explicitly to your pom file & exclude older/other version of dependencies.

(If the two versions are not compatible then your dependencies which require the ones you just excluded may break)

- No

Then let those dependencies be as they are.